# Xcode: cannot change version of project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am not able to change the version of project.
I've tried to change version with Target->General->[Version and Build]

[image]

Also, I tried to change version in AppName-info.plist

[image]

However, when I archive this project I get build with wrong version

[image]

When I am trying submit to Appstore, this error occures

[image]

How to solve it? All help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is your app version in itunes connect ?

Comment: If your itunes connect have version 1.2 then your xcode version also should have 1.2

Comment: @Mr.T In itunes app version is 1.1

Comment: Did you try my asnwer @Zhanserik

Comment: @Mr.T yeah, so it also didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. 
In Target->Build Phases I found script

```
git=$(sh /etc/profile; which git)
git_release_version=$("$git" describe --tags --always --abbrev=0)
number_of_commits=$("$git" rev-list master | wc -l | tr -d ' ')
target_plist="$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
dsym_plist="$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME/Contents/Info.plist"

for plist in "$target_plist" "$dsym_plist"; do
  if [ -f "$plist" ]; then
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $number_of_commits" "$plist"
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString ${git_release_version#*v}" "$plist"
  fi
done
```

Then I just removed it.

Comment: Using the git commit hash will mean git is permanently out-of-date given the file you are updating is tracked by git.

Comment: This helped me too!

Comment: I have a question here. How can I submit the app to App Store using this script? I mean I am getting this error while submitting the app to the app store. "The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key"

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to itunes connect

2. Go to my apps

3.Click on new version

4.Enter the new version number under Store version number

5. Enter the same version number in xcode,like you did and try to archive the project

Answer (score 0):

I think Build should be integer number ... Version should be 1.x

Build is the pure total number of build that you have made

for example

**Version: 1.3**

**Build: 30**

Comment: Oh, It didn't help :(